# Angular2 $event how to add to target databind or structure directive?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with a data transfer across view, within a component.
I make drag&drop; when i drag the data add to a component variable, then i drop the data, it add to local variable of method.

VIEW:

```
<tr>

              <td class="imported-table_data">
                  <h3>User name</h3>
                  <p>Simple name</p>
              </td>

              <td pDroppable="dd"
                  (onDrop)="dropped($event)"
                  class="imported-table_field" >
              </td></tr>


<tr *ngFor="let data of tableData" class="instance-table_row">
    <td pDraggable="dd" class="instance-table_data (onDragStart)="dragStart($event, data)">
     <h3>{{ data.title }}</h3>
     <p>{{ data?.data }}</p>
    </td>

</tr>
```

COMPONENT:

```
 dropped (event: Event) : void {
let data = this.tableCurrentData;
console.log('-----------------');
console.log(event);
console.log('-----------------');
this.tableCurrentData = null;}




dragStart (event: Event, data: any) : void {
console.log(event);
this.tableCurrentData = data;}
```

In this case, i got event.target which have current TD, how can i add my selected data, to current TD?

Comment: you can use for Drop as a sample reply,it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your `(onDragStart)` should you use that :

```
 this.onDragStart.emit({
  data: yourdata,
  event:yourdata
  //other variable
})
```

and you should use for your function in `html`

```
<td pDraggable="dd" class="instance-table_data (onDragStart)="dragStart($event.event,$event.data)">
```

and in your function in Typescript file:

```
public dragStart(event: any, data: string) {
//your code here
}
```